# Trying to lower compile SDK version from 23 to 22 throwing error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flock.alert"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'




    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'


}
```

Issue :

/Projects/Flock Alert/Abcd/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Android Studio/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: this line problamatic your build tool version buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"  it should 22.0

Comment: @Ajay Pandya, still same issue

Comment: after that change need to rebuild gradle again

Comment: nothing happen after rebuild..

Comment: Ok so try this if your sdk is up to date you can add this line for your material button compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Comment: It seems correct. Try to use gradle clean and then assemble again

Answer (score 0):

By changing your target API level from 23 to 22 in this app, you're entering into a conflict, because your app defines resources that are specifically used in API level 23 in this file (or some other file derived from resources targeting API level 23):

```
res/values-v23/values-v23.xml
```

Because this resource file lives in values-v23, it is saying that these resources are specifically targeting API level 23.  If you really must target API level 22, then you should remove all references to resources that target API level 23, such as this one.

Comment: which references i have to remove ?

Comment: I can't see your whole app so I have no idea.  You'll have to debug this by reading the error messages to find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build tool version 32.0.2 to 22.0.1
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

to
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"